# UITextView height is wrong in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` which resizes based on its content. But iOS9 gives wrong height value. I tried [UITextView height according to content is wrong in iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782716/uitextview-height-according-to-content-is-wrong-in-ios-9) . But this does not solve my issue. My textview is within a table view cell and my cell height changes based on textview height.

```
newSize = [_cell.detailedTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(_cell.detailedTextView.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(_cell.detailedTextView.bounds))];
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this one. It may be helpful to you

```
  + (CGFloat)gettextViewHeight:(UITextView*)textView
  {
     CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, 20000.0f);
     CGSize size;

      NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
      CGSize boundingBox = [textView.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:textView.font}
                                              context:context].size;

      size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));

      return size.height;
  }
```

Comment: It has reduced, but still there is a little more space.

Comment: which space you have got?

Comment: Around 50 points extra. This occurs only when the number of lines in textview is more than 10 lines

Comment: But will it affect other cells when number of lines is less?

Comment: I checked it out and I realized that issue comes only for iPhone 6  and iPhone 6 Plus, not for iPhone 5s with iOS 9

Comment: lblHeight = [Utility getLabelHeight:cell.lblbusinessAddress];
    
    CGRect newFrame = cell.lblbusinessAddress.frame;
    
  try this one --- >   newFrame.size.height = lblHeight;
    cell.lblbusinessAddress.frame = newFrame;
    
    lblHeight = lblHeight-24;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111213/discussion-between-jms-and-vijay-kachhadiya).

Comment: I think this issue might be because we have attributed text in uitextview

Comment: yes, you can take label instead of textVIew it was work for me

Comment: But does not have hyperlink property

Comment: you can use third party sdk for it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that boundingRect is calculated for cap heights, not for font ascenders. This causes the whole line not to appear.

[image: cap height vs ascender]

Once you account for that it displays correctly:

```
func height(of string: String, in textView: UITextView) -> CGFloat 
{
    let font = textView.font ?? UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
    let width = textView.bounds.size.width - 2.0 * textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding
    let size = CGSize(width: width,
                      height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let height = string.boundingRect(with: size,
                                     options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                                     attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font],
                                     context: nil).size.height
    let insets = textView.textContainerInset.top + textView.textContainerInset.bottom
    let diff = ceil(font.ascender - font.capHeight)
    return height + insets + diff
}
```